# parsing text file without splitting up multi-word names

Tags: python, regex, parsing, text, python-3.x

I am trying to use a text file to take the numerical output from an xml and turn it into a name that is then written to a separate text file. my problem is that the name sometimes has spaces in it and I'm not sure how to deal with this.

The program access several txt and xml files online where items are referred to by a reference number. It compares info from these files to criteria i set and then adds the reference number to a list. What i am trying to do is convert this reference number to the associated name. I have a text file with the reference numbers and names and want to use the index() function to find the reference number and then write the associated name to a text file. I'm having trouble parsing it so that I can do the conversion. My problem is the list is written like this:

```
number    name\n
14        apple\n
27        anjou pear\n
36        asian pear\n
7645      langsat\n
```

so if I just use the .split() i end up with some of the names being split. I have tried replacing the white space between the numbers and names with a '\n' and splitting it at that but that didn't work either. If I replace the space with ' , ' and split over that I end up the names including the next lines number ['apple\n15'] which writes to text as two lines and leaves me with the same problem of not being able to split it over the white space...

any advice???

I have now implemented the Dict() function as suggested bellow which works ACCEPT that I still have the \n at the end of the name...

```
ttn = dict()
f=open('typeid2.txt', 'r')
    for line in f:
    number, name = line.split(None,1)
    ttn[number] = name
```

if I call `ttn['14']` i get `'apple\n'`

Comment: use ttn[number].strip()  better yet change the line.split(None,1) to line.strip().split(None,1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regular expressions are very powerful and useful but it takes a lot to get used to using them with some authority.  I would suggest instead that you stick with split here is the help info from split that describes how to use a maxsplit value to limit the number of splits.

```
Help on built-in function split:

split(...)
S.split([sep [,maxsplit]]) -> list of strings

Return a list of the words in the string S, using sep as the
delimiter string.  If maxsplit is given, at most maxsplit
splits are done. If sep is not specified or is None, any
whitespace string is a separator and empty strings are removed
from the result.
```

So for your code, assuming you have some lines to split

```
mytest = dict()
for each_line in data:
    number, name = line.split(None,1)
    mytest[number] = name
```

will return something like this

> > > mytest
> > >           {'27': 'anjou pear', '7645': 'langsat', 'number': 'name', '36': 'asian pear', '14': 'apple'}
> > >       to access the help suppose you have some string mystring then just type

```
help(mystring.split)
```

The difference between my first attempt and this one was due to the comment below.  In my first attempt the leading spaces on the name value were retained however, by using None, all white space characters were removed on the first split so this gets more specifically to what you are looking for.

Comment: Use `split(None,1)` instead to automagically trim the whitespace between the values.

Comment: so basically i would use this to create a new list and then index to that list? also, could you show how to save that list instead of printing it? I have over 8000 entries so printing them all would be kind of obnoxious...

i tired to do an example but i apparently suck at using the comment system...

Comment: @user3391121 I only printed it to demonstrate that the method worked.  Your next question is how to save this in a way that is persistent.  That is not to hard but the method used needs to address your use case.  However, in keeping with the guidelines here you should select one of these answers as the one that best addresses your needs and then ask another question.  However, I don't think you will need to ask a question - search here for [python] [dictionary] save and see if some of those answers will guide you.  I glanced and the first couple look like they address your needs

Comment: well my question was "What i am trying to do is convert this reference number to the associated name". this almost answers my question, if I could save it to a new file which i could then index. I tried to replace the 'print(number, name)' with 'g.write(number, name)' ('g=open('newfile.txt', 'w')' previous to this) and i get no errors but no text either. 'g.write(str(number, name))' is the same. also, i had to change it to 'for line in f:'. Im using 3.3 so i assume thats why the difference in syntax

Comment: I put it in a dictionary instead if the list is large there are great advantages for a dictionary over a list.  For one you can avoid iterating through the list on every lookup.

Comment: DICTIONARY!!! holy genius. that will work like a charm. Thank you, I will update with the "answer" in a few

Answer (score 1):

You can use `re.findall()` for this purpose.

```
input = "number    name\n14        apple\n27        anjou pear\n36        asian pear\n7645      langsat\n"
print re.findall("(\w+)\s+(.+)", input)
```

output:

```
[('number', 'name'), ('14', 'apple'), ('27', 'anjou pear'), ('36', 'asian pear'), ('7645', 'langsat')]
```

Comment: this did exactly what you said it would and seems to have gotten rid of the \n but i can't figure out how to search it for the id number and associate it with the name. I think i would have to split it up again but it's a tuple now so I'm having trouble with it. Any more advice on finishing this off??? (the name number combos are now single items within the tuple so if i were to say `t[1]` it would return `('14', 'apple')`)